# Вернуть html с сервера и распознать как json

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Проблема с поиском.

html:

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" class="navbar-search pull-right" id="searchValid">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Поиск..">
  <select name="nubexSelect" id="nubexSelect" size="1">
    <option value="1">Имя</option>
    <option value="2">Фамилия</option>
    <option value="3">E-Mail</option>
    <option value="4">Дата регистрации</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="sbm" name="sbm" value="Найти">
</form>
```

ajax:

```html
$('#searchValid').ajaxForm({
 url: '/admin/users/search/search',
 dataType: 'text',
 success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  data = $.parseJSON(data);
  switch(data.status) {
   case 'error':
    $.jGrowl(data.error, { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-red" });
    $('input[type=sbm]').prop('disabled', false);
    break;
   case 'success':
    $.jGrowl(data.success, { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-green" });
    setTimeout("reload()", 1000);
    break;
  }
 },
 beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
  $('input[type=sbm]').prop('disabled', true);
 }
});
```

search.php

```html
class searchController extends Controller {
 private $limit = 20;
 public function search($page = 1) {
  $this->document->setActiveSection('admin');
  $this->document->setActiveItem('users');
  
  if(!$this->user->isLogged()) {
   $this->session->data['error'] = "Вы не авторизированы!";
   $this->response->redirect($this->config->url . 'account/login');
  }
  if($this->user->getAccessLevel() < 2) {
   $this->session->data['error'] = "У вас нет доступа к данному разделу!";
   $this->response->redirect($this->config->url);
  }
  
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $this->load->model('users');
  
  $options = array(
   'start' => ($page - 1) * $this->limit,
   'limit' => $this->limit
  );
  
  $total = $this->usersModel->getTotalUsers();
  
  if($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $search = @$this->request->post['search'];
   
   $returnArray = array(); 
   $row = 0; 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_firstname LIKE '%ара%'");// %ара% — поставил пока просто для теста
   while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    $returnArray[$row] = $result; 
    $row++; 
   }
   $users = $returnArray;
  }
  
  $paginationLib = new paginationLibrary();
  
  $paginationLib->total = $total;
  $paginationLib->page = $page;
  $paginationLib->limit = $this->limit;
  $paginationLib->url = $this->config->url . 'adminls/users/search/search/{page}';
  
  $pagination = $paginationLib->render();
  
  $this->data['users'] = $users;
  $this->data['status'] = $status;
  $this->data['pagination'] = $pagination;
  
  $this->getChild(array('common/header', 'common/footer'));
  //return $this->load->view('admin/users/index', $this->data);
  //return json_encode($this->data);
 }
}
```

В конце `search.php` есть такие строки:

```html
//return $this->load->view('admin/users/index', $this->data);
//return json_encode($this->data);
```

Если раскомментировать 1-ую строку, то консоль в браузере выдает: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`
Если раскомментировать 2-ую строку, то консоль не выдает ошибку, но и html страницу не загружает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разобраться?

Comment: А если посмотреть во вкладку сеть, в содержимое ответов на ваши ajax запросы? В обоих случаях.

Comment: @Visman, в обоих случая выводит отсортированных пользователей. Только, если `return $this->load->view('admin/users/index', $this->data);`, то выводит как html, а если `return json_encode($this->data);`, то просто в строку пишет.

Comment: Подскажите, какой результат и где вы ожидаете ?
"html страницу не загружает" А куда она должна загружаться ?
Код Ajax подразумевает, что ответ должен быть json. Но обработки этого json нет - лишь вывод статуса запроса всплывающим сообщением. В data.users лежат данные, но они код не интересуют. 
Если в PHP есть вариант вывода html, то стоило бы на стороне браузера предусмотреть контейнер для результатов и грузить туда html код через $.load()